# Actionscript code works fine in Adobe Flash but not in Flash Player or html

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash

I have written code in Actionscript 3.0 (using CS4) that executes fine within the Flash programming interface. When I publish it as a .swf or .html, however, running these using Flash Player or a browser gives nothing but a blank window.

Possibly relevant: The code is in two parts, a mainline and a package, but I assume that Flash publishes the two together. It all runs in a single frame.

```
import Quadrilateral;
import flash.display.Stage; 
import flash.display.StageAlign; 
import flash.display.StageScaleMode; 
var pow:Function = Math.pow;
var cos:Function = Math.cos;
var sin:Function = Math.sin;
var acos:Function = Math.acos;
var PI:Number = Math.PI;

        var canvas:Sprite = new Sprite();
        var gr:Graphics = canvas.graphics;
        canvas.alpha = .6;
        this.addChild(canvas);
        var offset:Point = new Point(200,170);
        var a:Number=160;                       //a, b, and c are side lengths
        var c:Number=135;
        var angleb:Number=52*PI/180;        //anglea and angleb are the angles at vertex A and B
        var C:Point = new Point(a*cos(angleb), a*sin(angleb)).add(offset);      //A, B, and C are vertices 
        var B:Point = new Point(0,0).add(offset);
        var A:Point = new Point(c,0).add(offset);   
        var b:Number = Point.distance(C,A);
        var anglea:Number = acos((pow(b,2)+pow(c,2)-pow(a,2))/(2*c*b));
        var anglec:Number = PI - anglea - angleb;
//the following are the feet of altitudes from A to side a, B to side B, etc.
        var aA:Point = new Point(c*pow(cos(angleb),2), c*cos(angleb)*sin(angleb)).add(offset);
        var bB:Point = new Point(c*pow(sin(anglea),2), c*cos(anglea)*sin(anglea)).add(offset);
        var cC:Point = new Point(a*cos(angleb), 0).add(offset);
        var colors:Array = new Array(0xFF0000, 0x0009F0, 0x990099, 0x990099, 0x990099, 0xFF0000);
        var triangleColor:Number = 0x20D1D1;
        var steps:Number = 100;
        var timer = new Timer(10000, 1);    

        drawTriangle(A,B,C);
        var quada1:Quadrilateral = new Quadrilateral(B, aA,  a, colors[0], steps, canvas, 1);
        var quadb1:Quadrilateral = new Quadrilateral(A, bB,  b, colors[1], steps, canvas, -1);
        var quadc1:Quadrilateral = new Quadrilateral(C, bB,  b, colors[2], steps, canvas, 1);

/*      var quada2:Quadrilateral = new Quadrilateral(C, aA,  a, Point.distance(B,bB), colors[colorcount++], steps, canvas, -1);
        var quadb2:Quadrilateral = buildRectangle(C, bB, -b, B);
        var quadc2:Quadrilateral = buildRectangle(cC, B, c, C);
        */
        quada1.drawSquare(C, aA);
        quadb1.drawSquare(B, cC);
        quadc1.drawSquare(A, bB);
        gr.lineStyle(1,0xA0A0A0);
        connect(A,aA);
        connect(B,bB);
        connect(C,cC);
        quada1.go(A, angleb, -1, 0);
        timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, nextside);
        timer.start();
        stop();
        function nextside(e:TimerEvent) {
            quadb1.go(B, anglea, 1, 0);
            timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, nextside);
            timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, lastside);
            timer.start();
        }
        function lastside(e:TimerEvent) {
            quadc1.go(B, anglec, -1, -(anglea+anglec));
            timer.stop();
        }
        function drawTriangle(p1:Point, p2:Point, p3:Point) {
            gr.beginFill(triangleColor);
            gr.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
            gr.lineTo(p2.x, p2.y);
            gr.lineTo(p3.x, p3.y);
            gr.endFill();
        }
        function connect(p1:Point, p2:Point) {
            gr.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
            gr.lineTo(p2.x, p2.y);
        }
```

Comment: What version of flash player do you have installed? Try to install the most recent debugger standalone player or the plugin for your browser and see if any errors come up during execution.

Comment: Also helpful is trying to reduce your code to the most minimal code that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: The debugger was a great suggestion -- I didn't know it existed. The program now works in a browser. (The problem was that the program's attempt to go to fullscreen mode, which was being rejected. I removed this) The .swf is still non-functional, however, for unknown reasons.

Comment: The .swf file was not running because it was being opened by an old version of Flash Shockwave Player. Thanks for all the help!